# Chrome Invalid SSL Certificate Security Warning

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl

I ran into an interesting problem today using Chrome and I'm hoping there is a better way to fix it than what I ended up doing.

The issue starts with an invalid SSL certificate on a site that I'm configuring. In Chrome it's possible to advance past this screen using a link which adds a security exception for the current domain so that you don't have to view this warning message again.

[image: Your connection is not private Chrome warning]

It's also possible to clear this warning by going to the site with the exception then clicking the **Not secure** text and choosing the **Re-enable warnings** option.

[image: Re-enable warnings option in Chrome]

Now my problem, I have a couple different redirects in place on the site that will redirect my .com and .bank domains to the primary .net domain. While developing I added security exceptions for all three of these domains. This becomes and issue when testing that my SSL certificate is configured properly. I want to clear out Chrome's stored exception for the .com domain - but I cannot do so using the **Re-enable warnings** option because as soon as I arrive at the page Chrome sees that an exception is already stored and proceeds to load the page normally which then gets redirected to the .net domain. Because of this there is no point where I can actually clear out the bypassed security warning in Chrome...

The only way I've been able to find to clear out these exceptions is to use the **Reset** option in Chrome's settings, which is not something I want to do regularly. I'm wondering if there is a hidden settings page in Chrome that lists all of the bypassed security warnings so that I may clear them out individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "Re-enable warnings" for all SSL warnings if you don't want to clear your history (or if you dont know all the exemptions you have in place), you can close Chrome and edit: 
   `"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"`
and set     `ssl_cert_decisions":{},"`

Stored in the JSON-path:

> profile > content_settings > exceptions > ssl_cert_decisions

Or you can change the decision_expiration_time of the specific exemption to be equal to the last_modified time

Example:    `"ssl_cert_decisions":{"https://expired.badssl.com:443,*":{"last_modified":"13235055329485008","setting":{"cert_exceptions_map":{"-201cgaDTf2DD6Cj0N6/tKvudkzDuRBA3GwKd8T9hE7mHhQ=":1},"decision_expiration_time":"13235055329485008","version":1}}}`

Comment: even though it took 3 years and i'm a couple jobs away from that project i appreciate your response!

Answer (score 0):

you will have to clear the browsing data for that site, the easiest way I found to do this is (Ctrl+Shift+Del) to bring the clear browser data window up then set time range to 1 hour, choose browsing history only then click clear data. Hope this is useful.

[image: Clear browser data dialog]